# Multible names for snippet in snipmate

Tags: vim, snippets

I'm wondering if it possible to have a snippet with several names. For example a snipped for a title which can be expanded using title and ti. Of course it would be possible to add it twice, for each name once, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I don't think so. You can have multiple snippets with the same trigger but not multiple triggers for one snippet. Maybe it's possible in UltiSnips?

Answer (score 0):

Though most snippets are defined in `snippets/<filetype>.snippets` files,  they can also be defined in separate files `snippets/<filetype>/<trigger>.snippet`. If you use that, you can use filesystem (hard or symbolic, junctions on Windows) links to have two files `title.snippet` and `ti.snippet` with identical contents.